# SurveyJS Survey Creator what class do I extend if I want to use the Image Picker default rendering in custom widget JQuery?

Tags: surveyjs

I would like to make a custom widget in order to add a new question type to the SurveyJS Survey Creator toolbox.
I am extending the Survey.QuestionImagePickerModel and overriding getType() for my custom class.
What class do I extend for the image picker renderer default functionality?
How do I register this class/ use it to render my custom widget in JQuery?
Does isDefaultRender: true use the default renderer of the current question type?
Does isDefaultRender: true not use the default renderer of the parent element specified in Survey.Serializer.addClass?

The property grid for my custom question mostly matches the imagepicker property grid; however, nothing renders in the preview and only the action bar renders in the creator, none of my image choices show up nor is there a image upload option.
I am trying to follow this example and convert it to JQuery for image picker instead of question:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crimson-https-3gy8cr?file=%2Fsrc%2FSurveyCreatorComponent.jsx%3A87%2C1-121%2C3